# HTML to PDF with Node.js

Tags: node.js, express, pdf-generation

I'm looking to create a printable `pdf` version of my website webpages. Something like `express.render()` only render the page as `pdf`

Does anyone know a node module that does that ?

If not, how would you go about implementing one ? I've seen some methods talk about using headless browser like `phantom.js`, but not sure whats the flow.

Comment: I hope this will be still relevant, but there is this site now https://simpe.li which has some predefined templates that you can pick and use. Could be useful in some situations.

Comment: Support for phantom has ceased, so I would use this solution your own risk!

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Extending upon Mustafa's answer.

A) Install http://phantomjs.org/ and then

B) install the phantom node module https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node

[image]

C) Here is an example of rendering a pdf

```
var phantom = require('phantom');   

phantom.create().then(function(ph) {
    ph.createPage().then(function(page) {
        page.open("http://www.google.com").then(function(status) {
            page.render('google.pdf').then(function() {
                console.log('Page Rendered');
                ph.exit();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

**Output of the PDF:**

[image]

**EDIT:** [Silent printing that PDF](http://apache.cu.be/pdfbox/2.0.2/pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar)

`java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar PrintPDF -silentPrint C:\print_mypdf.pdf`

Comment: Does this also load the CSS ? When I render a page, text is shown but there is no CSS.

Comment: One of the issue with this solution is, you will not get clickable links that are on the webpage. This is same as taking a screen shot and embedding the image into PDF. If that works foryou, then this a great solution.

Comment: This module `phantomjs-node` does not exist on NPM, use `npm install phantom@2 -S` for node v less than 5.0 or `npm install phantom -S` for node version 5.0 or greater

Comment: When i convert html to pdf, there are 4-5 page in html. I want to use page break between two page. This is my url link which i want to convert in pdf.

"http://ishtech.xyz//web/#/reports_view?StartDate=11/14/2017&EndDate=12/08/2017&Area=&UserCompanyID=7&IsDefect=false"

Comment: Working well but I've `Google Map` and `Spyder Chart` which is not displayed well spyder chart have animation. Can we set Timeout for creating pdf or wait till the whole page loaded?

Comment: can this work with invalid URLs (for example, google chrome extensions result pages such as (chrome-extension://particularExtensionID/templates/gtar.html#!/report))?  What can I use to convert that entire page to pdf?

Comment: PhantomJS is no longer an active project

Answer (score 24):

[Phantom.js](http://phantomjs.org/) is an headless webkit server and it will load any web page and render it in memory, although you might not be able to see it, there is a Screen Capture feature, in which you can export the current view as PNG, PDF, JPEG and GIF. Have a look at this [example from phantom.js documentation](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html)

Answer (score 19):

Try to use Puppeteer to create PDF from HTML

Example from here https://github.com/chuongtrh/html_to_pdf

Or https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer

Comment: puppeteer makes more sense than phantom now as the latter has been deprecated and the former has much better and stable apis.

Comment: Puppeteer is the only way to create PDF from HTML, using modern markup.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to export HTML to PDF. You have many options. without node even

Option 1: Have a button on your html page that calls window.print() function. use the browsers native html to pdf. use media queries to make your html page look good on a pdf. and you also have the print before and after events that you can use to make changes to your page before print.

Option 2. [htmltocanvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) or [rasterizeHTML](https://github.com/cburgmer/rasterizeHTML.js). convert your html to canvas , then call toDataURL() on the canvas object to get the image . and use a JavaScript library like [jsPDF](http://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to add that image to a PDF file. Disadvantage of this approach is that the pdf doesnt become editable. If you want data extracted from PDF, there is different ways for that.

Option 3. @Jozzhard answer

Comment: Which browsers have a built-in html to pdf option? I can only see it in Chrome at this point.

Answer (score 12):

The best solution I found is html-pdf. It's simple and work with big html.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

Its as simple as that:

```
    pdf.create(htm, options).toFile('./pdfname.pdf', function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
    });
```

### NOTE:

**This package has been deprecated**

> **Author message: Please migrate your projects to a newer library like puppeteer**

Comment: Absolutely awesome. It works with external URLs too if you combine it with requestify.

Comment: It takes in account the css? the classes?

Comment: @gabodev77, yes it does.

Comment: its support style tag or not ?

Comment: FYI - this package hasn't been updated since 2017 and has a critical vulnerability https://www.npmjs.com/advisories/1095
Probably best to go with another option :)

Comment: The library is deprecated. Please update/remove this answer.

Comment: https://github.com/ultimateakash/puppeteer-html-pdf

Answer (score 8):

**Package**

I used [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)

Easy to use and allows not only to save pdf as file, but also pipe pdf content to a WriteStream (so I could stream it directly to Google Storage to save there my reports).

**Using css + images**

It takes css into account. The only problem I faced - it ignored my images. The solution I found was to replace url in `src` attrribute value by base64, e.g.

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR...kSuQmCC">`

You can do it with your code or to use one of online converters, e.g. https://www.base64-image.de/

**Compile valid html code from html fragment + css**

1. I had to get a fragment of my `html` document (I just appiled .html() method on jQuery selector).
2. Then I've read the content of the relevant `css` file.

Using this two values (stored in variables `html` and `css` accordingly) I've compiled a valid html code using [Template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings)

```
var htmlContent = `
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      ${css}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body id=direct-sellers-bill>
    ${html}
  </body>
</html>`
```

and passed it to `create` method of [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf).

Comment: Can html-pdf download from invalid urls, such as from Google Chrome extension / gtar.html pages?

Comment: how to you expect any system to get anything from an invalid url?

Comment: An image can be loaded from a file, just a correct location has to be set with `file://` prefix. So, you say in template `<img src="static/logo.png">`, then before converting, prepare template by prefixing `const html = htmlOrig.replace(new RegExp('<img src="', 'g'), \`<img src="${base}\`);`

Answer (score 6):

**Create PDF from External URL**

Here's an adaptation of the previous answers which utilizes `html-pdf`, but also combines it with `requestify` so it works with an external URL:

Install your dependencies

```
npm i -S html-pdf requestify
```

Then, create the script:

```
//MakePDF.js

var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var requestify = require('requestify');
var externalURL= 'http://www.google.com';

requestify.get(externalURL).then(function (response) {
   // Get the raw HTML response body
   var html = response.body; 
   var config = {format: 'A4'}; // or format: 'letter' - see https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf#options

// Create the PDF
   pdf.create(html, config).toFile('pathtooutput/generated.pdf', function (err, res) {
      if (err) return console.log(err);
      console.log(res); // { filename: '/pathtooutput/generated.pdf' }
   });
});
```

Then you just run from the command line:

```
node MakePDF.js
```

Watch your beautify pixel perfect PDF be created for you (for free!)

Comment: There's an issue which causes `html-pdf` to only success at making the PDF sometimes - https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf/issues/181

Comment: How would you render the created PDF directly to the browser without having to store the file first?

Comment: Using a binary stream it could be done. Theoretically it doesn't get saved, just piped directly to the browser. Although working with node, I could only get it to work by first saving the temporary pdf, then getting the binary stream, downloading the binary stream, then deleting the temporary pdf.

Comment: I am getting an error from html-pdf - ReferenceError: Can't find variable $. Could this be happening because the page I am loading has javascript that needs to execute? Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: @TetraDev: i need to ristrict to generate 1 page pdf, what will be changes?

Answer (score 6):

For those who don't want to install PhantomJS along with an instance of Chrome/Firefox on their server - or because the [PhantomJS project is *currently* suspended](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/15344), here's an alternative.

You can externalize the conversions to APIs to do the job. Many exists and varies but what you'll get is a reliable service with up-to-date features (I'm thinking CSS3, Web fonts, SVG, Canvas compatible).

For instance, with [PDFShift](https://pdfshift.io) (disclaimer, I'm the founder), you can do this simply by using the `request` package:

```
const request = require('request')
request.post(
    'https://api.pdfshift.io/v2/convert/',
    {
        'auth': {'user': 'your_api_key'},
        'json': {'source': 'https://www.google.com'},
        'encoding': null
    },
    (error, response, body) => {
        if (response === undefined) {
            return reject({'message': 'Invalid response from the server.', 'code': 0, 'response': response})
        }
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
            // Do what you want with `body`, that contains the binary PDF
            // Like returning it to the client - or saving it as a file locally or on AWS S3
            return True
        }

        // Handle any errors that might have occured
    }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf)**

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const utils = require('util')
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const hb = require('handlebars')
const readFile = utils.promisify(fs.readFile)

async function getTemplateHtml() {

    console.log("Loading template file in memory")
    try {
        const invoicePath = path.resolve("./invoice.html");
        return await readFile(invoicePath, 'utf8');
    } catch (err) {
        return Promise.reject("Could not load html template");
    }
}


async function generatePdf() {

    let data = {};

    getTemplateHtml()
        .then(async (res) => {
            // Now we have the html code of our template in res object
            // you can check by logging it on console
            // console.log(res)

            console.log("Compiing the template with handlebars")
            const template = hb.compile(res, { strict: true });
            // we have compile our code with handlebars
            const result = template(data);
            // We can use this to add dyamic data to our handlebas template at run time from database or API as per need. you can read the official doc to learn more https://handlebarsjs.com/
            const html = result;

            // we are using headless mode 
            const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
            const page = await browser.newPage()

            // We set the page content as the generated html by handlebars
            await page.setContent(html)

            // we Use pdf function to generate the pdf in the same folder as this file.
            await page.pdf({ path: 'invoice.pdf', format: 'A4' })

            await browser.close();
            console.log("PDF Generated")

        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.error(err)
        });
}

generatePdf();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you arrive here looking for a way to make PDF from view templates in Express, a colleague and I made [express-template-to-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ministryofjustice/express-template-to-pdf)

which allows you to generate PDF from whatever templates you're using in Express - Pug, Nunjucks, whatever.

It depends on html-pdf and is written to use in your routes just like you use res.render:

```
const pdfRenderer = require('@ministryofjustice/express-template-to-pdf')

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'pug')

app.use(pdfRenderer())
```

If you've used res.render then using it should look obvious:

```
app.use('/pdf', (req, res) => {
    res.renderPDF('helloWorld', { message: 'Hello World!' });
})
```

You can pass options through to html-pdf to control the PDF document page size etc

Merely building on the excellent work of others.

Answer (score 0):

In my view, the best way to do this is via an API so that you do not add a large and complex dependency into your app that runs unmanaged code, that needs to be frequently updated.

Here is a simple way to do this, which is free for 800 requests/month:

```
var CloudmersiveConvertApiClient = require('cloudmersive-convert-api-client');
var defaultClient = CloudmersiveConvertApiClient.ApiClient.instance;

// Configure API key authorization: Apikey
var Apikey = defaultClient.authentications['Apikey'];
Apikey.apiKey = 'YOUR API KEY';



var apiInstance = new CloudmersiveConvertApiClient.ConvertWebApi();

var input = new CloudmersiveConvertApiClient.HtmlToPdfRequest(); // HtmlToPdfRequest | HTML to PDF request parameters
input.Html = "<b>Hello, world!</b>";


var callback = function(error, data, response) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
  }
};
apiInstance.convertWebHtmlToPdf(input, callback);
```

With the above approach you can also install the API on-premises or on your own infrastructure if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jozzhart Answer, you can make a local html; serve it with express; and use phantom to make PDF from it; something like this:

```
const exp = require('express');
const app = exp();
const pth = require("path");
const phantom = require('phantom');
const ip = require("ip");

const PORT = 3000;
const PDF_SOURCE = "index"; //index.html
const PDF_OUTPUT = "out"; //out.pdf

const source = pth.join(__dirname, "", `${PDF_SOURCE}.html`);
const output = pth.join(__dirname, "", `${PDF_OUTPUT}.pdf`);

app.use("/" + PDF_SOURCE, exp.static(source));
app.use("/" + PDF_OUTPUT, exp.static(output));

app.listen(PORT);

let makePDF = async (fn) => {
    let local = `http://${ip.address()}:${PORT}/${PDF_SOURCE}`;
    phantom.create().then((ph) => {
        ph.createPage().then((page) => {
            page.open(local).then(() =>
                page.render(output).then(() => { ph.exit(); fn() })
            );
        });
    });
}

makePDF(() => {
    console.log("PDF Created From Local File");
    console.log("PDF is downloadable from link:");
    console.log(`http://${ip.address()}:${PORT}/${PDF_OUTPUT}`);
});
```

and index.html can be anything:

```
<h1>PDF HEAD</h1>
<a href="#">LINK</a>
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/dynamic-html-pdf

I use dynamic-html-pdf, this is simple and also able to pass dynamic variable to html.

```
var html = fs.readFileSync('./uploads/your-html-tpl.html', 'utf8');
var options = {
    format: "A4",
    orientation: "portrait"
    // border: "10mm"
};
var document = {
    type: 'file',     // 'file' or 'buffer'
    template: html,
    context: {
       'your_key':'your_values'
    },
    path: '/pdf/1.pdf'   // pdf save path
};

pdf.create(document, options)
.then(res => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch(error => {
    console.error(error)
});
```

On html you can use {{your_key}}

Answer (score 0):

I've written [hpdf](https://github.com/frimuchkov/hpdf) lib for generating PDF from HTLM or URL.
It supports configurable pool of headless browsers (as resources) in the background.

```js
import fs from 'fs';
import { PdfGenerator } from './src';

const start = async () => {
    const generator = new PdfGenerator({
        min: 3,
        max: 10,
    });

    const helloWorld = await generator.generatePDF('<html lang="html">Hello World!</html>');
    const github = await generator.generatePDF(new URL('https://github.com/frimuchkov/hpdf'));

    await fs.promises.writeFile('./helloWorld.pdf', helloWorld);
    await fs.promises.writeFile('./github.pdf', github);

    await generator.stop();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add to this since I did not see the option to created pdfs from liquid templates yet, but the solution also works with normal html or urls as well.

Lets say this is our html template. Which could be anything really but see that the code include double curly braces. The key inside the braces will be looked up in the *liquid_data* parameter of the request and replaced by the value.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>{{heading}}</h1>
    <img src="{{img_url}}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

The corresponding *liquid_data* object looks like this:

```
{
  "heading":"Hi Stackoverflow!",
  "img_url":"https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg"
}
```

This is the example I want to create a PDF for. Using [pdfEndpoint](https://pdfendpoint.com) and the [Playground](https://pdfendpoint.com/playground) creating a pdf from that template from above is very simple.

```
const axios = require("axios");

const options = {
  method: "POST",
  url: "https://api.pdfendpoint.com/v1/convert",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Authorization": "Bearer SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY"
  },
  data: {
    "delivery_mode": "json",
    "page_size": "A4",
    "margin_top": "1cm",
    "margin_bottom": "1cm",
    "margin_left": "1cm",
    "margin_right": "1cm",
    "orientation": "vertical",
    "html": "<html><body> <h1>{{heading}}</h1> <img src=\"{{img_url}}\"/>      </body>\</html>",
    "parse_liquid": true,
    "liquid_data": "{  \"heading\":\"Hi Stackoverflow!\",  \"img_url\":\"https://stackoverflow.design/assets/img/logos/so/logo-stackoverflow.svg\"}"
  }
};

axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
  console.log(response.data);
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.error(error);
});
```

The service will the return a rendered pdf like this:
[image: Html to pdf rendered with pdfendpoint.com]

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with various packages, I found that `Puppeteer` was the most suitable, and this is what worked for me.

My `Controller.js`

```
        const fs = require("fs");
        const express = require("express");
        // const html_to_pdf = require("html-pdf-node");
        const path = require("path");
        const pdf = require("html-pdf");
        const ejs = require("ejs");
        const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
        //if u want to import additional methods from other js file and pass it to ejs
        const ejs_helpers = require("../views/report/helpers");
        const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


        const generatePdfFromEjs = async (req,res) => {
                      const filePathName = path.resolve("public/views/report/home.ejs");
                      const htmlString = fs.readFileSync(filePathName).toString();
                      //using puppeteer
                      const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
                      const [page] = await browser.pages();
                      const additionalData = {};
                      const html = await ejs.render(htmlString, { helpers: ejs_helpers, ...additionalData });
                      await page.setContent(html);
                      const pdf = await page.pdf({ format: "A4", printBackground: true });
                      res.contentType("application/pdf");
                      res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=report.pdf");
                      // can upload to S3 bucket if needed
                      const uploadParams = {
                        Bucket: "XYZ",
                        Key: `filename.pdf`,
                        Body: pdf,
                      };
                      s3.upload(uploadParams, (err, data) => {
                        if (err) {
                          console.log("error", err);
                          rej("");
                        }
                        console.log(data.Location);
                        return data.Location;
                      });
                      res.send(pdf);
       }
```

My `Home.ejs`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    #print-report .introFooter {
      background-image: url("https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg") !important; /* adding important is mandatory then onnly it will reflect */
      background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
      background-size: cover !important;
      padding: 0 20px 25px 20px;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="print-report">
    <div class="introFooter">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="idHeader">Date :</span>Test</span></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="idHeader">Date :</span>Test</span></div>
          <div class="col-xs-4"><span class="idHeader">Date :</span>Test</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div ><img class="brandDivider" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="img"></div>
      <div>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    </div>
    </h1>
    <%- include('./file.ejs', {data:{}}) %>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also use pdf node creator package

Package URL -
https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node