# Cross-platform html to pdf library for node-webkit

Tags: node.js, pdf, pdf-generation, node-webkit

I wrote a cross-platform application using node-webkit. I have the needs to generate PDF from HTML+CSS and to package and distribute my application to Win, Linux and Mac.

I have known some nice libraries such as, PhantomJS, wkhtmltopdf can do this stuff. But I don't know how to integrate these libs into my node-webkit and works cross-platforms?

Thx for any idea.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552112/html-to-pdf-with-node-js?lq=1

Comment: @staaar they focus on how to generate pdf. My question is mainly on how to integrate pdf generation lib(e.g. wkhtmltopdf, phantomjs) to node-webkit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org/)

It's JavaScript so you don't need any external libs, just install it via npm.

Otherwise there is [wkhtmltopdf npm package](https://www.npmjs.org/package/wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: PDFKit can't transform a HTML to PDF. Also, wkhtmltopdf depends on the installed wkhtmltopdf, so it is difficult to package and distribute it with node-webkit.