# How to convert html to pdf in node js without exe

Tags: html, node.js, pdf

I'm looking for a *node.js* module, which is able to generate PDF from HTML.

I know there are many options e.g. *phantomjs*, *wkhtmltopdf*. All this utilities require some command line tools.

I need something, that is easy to install (only `npm install xxx`) and is ready for use. I also don't want to call it by requests (REST API). Do anybody know something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552112/html-to-pdf-with-node-js

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to give [**pdfkitjs**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pdfkitjs) or [**pdfmake**](https://www.npmjs.org/package/pdfmake) a try. Both the projects are available as npm modules and are [pretty](https://github.com/LoicMahieu/pdfkitjs) [well](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake) documented on github.

Comment: pdfmake's note "_links to the documentation do NOT work yet_" does not look like indicator that something is pretty well documented and [semver](http://semver.org/) major version number 0 also does not look like indicator of a reliable tool for public use (anyway I'm voting +1)

Comment: @xmojmr, you're right. But the repo is pretty active and the issues raised are addressed by the developers promptly as far as pdfmake is concerned. I get your point though, thanks for mentioning it :)

Comment: @xmojmr Getting started + playground samples cover pretty much everything so after writing it I decided not to duplicate the docs :)

Comment: @bartekp my compliments to the pdfmake author. The most up-to-date documentation can be found at http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted ?

Comment: @xmojmr yes, it's the most up-to-date source of information