# A similar solution to html2canvas with nodejs

Tags: html, css, node.js, html2canvas

I'm using css, jquery and nodejs (with ejs and express) to create a website and I need to export a div with some text and some divs with a background-image as an image (jpg or png) but the best would be pdf. I tried to use html2canvas but then I read that it is not compatible with nodejs. 
I also tried with jspdf but it doesn't export the css in the pdf file.
So I would like to know if anyone knows a solution that can do that with nodejs.

Here is an exemple of my ejs code :

```
<%for(var j = 0; j < rawData.scanner.length; ++j) {%>
<div class="grid" id="grid-<%= data.scanner[j].camera%>" 
    style="
    width : <%= parseFloat(data.widthScreen) + 17%>px; 
    height : <%= parseFloat(data.heightScreen) + 17%>px; 
    position : absolute;
    left : 0px;
    top : 60px;
    overflow-x : scroll;
    overflow-y : scroll;
    display : none;">
    <%for(var i = 0; i < data.scanner[j].parts; ++i) {%>
    <div class="fenetre" id=<%= data.scanner[j].name + "-img" + i%>
        style="
        background-image : url(<%= (data.scanner[j].imagePath)%>);
        width : <%= data.scanner[j].width%>px; 
        height : <%= data.scanner[j].height%>px; 
        position:absolute; 
        top: 0px; 
        left: <%= (i * data.scanner[j].left)%>px;"
    >
    </div>
    <%}%>
</div>
<%}%>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but these days I'd try [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

async function printPDF() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("http:///stackoverflow.com", {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });
  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    width: 1200,
    height: 1920,
    pageRanges: "1-2",
    path: "so.pdf",
  });

  await browser.close();
  return pdf;
}
printPDF();
```

Also see [HTML to PDF with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14552112/html-to-pdf-with-node-js)

Answer (score 0):

Try [html-pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf), it export css in pdf file and it is also a npm package so it will compatible with nodejs.

Installation:

`$ npm install -g html-pdf`

Command-line example:

`$ html-pdf test/businesscard.html businesscard.pdf`

Code example:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' } 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the awnser. Unfortunately, I'm using ejs so I don't have any .html files that I can read. Do you have another solution? (even if it's jpg or png instead of pdf, I'll take it)

Comment: Could you give me an example of your `div`,`images` & `css`?

Comment: I edited the question. I don't have .css file, the css is inline

Comment: you can JUST add the htlm & css into `html` variable. var html = '<h1> Your html code</h1>'

Comment: It surely helped me to convert HTML to PDF File. Else we can add HTML to a variable and can pass that to pdf.crate(<the variable of HTML tags>)

Comment: BUT **html-pdf ** have issue with rendering `css` code. its very hard to style document in html-pdf.