# How to create an image with HTML template in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have a HTML template file in node js. And I want to convert that template with into image by replacing static values with dynamic values. Suppose I have a below HTML template saved in any variable in my CONFIG file:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')
const htmlString = `<html>
                    <head>
                      <title></title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                      <div class="container" style="height:500px;width:450px;border:1px solid silver;margin:0 auto">
                        <header style="height:200px;background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/a1ItuWs.jpg');">
                            <center>
                              <span style="font-size:55px;color:white;font-weight: bold;font-family: arial;margin-top:20px">Hello</span>
                              <br>
                              <span style="font-size: 35px;color: white">rajat</span>
                              <br><br>
                              <span style="font-size:20px;color: white;font-family: arial;">from biondi Goh</span>
                            </center>
                        </header>
                        <section style="height: 280px;background: #ecfaff">
                          <center>
                            <span style="font-size: 30px;font-family: arial;">rajat subject</span>
                            <br><br>
                            <span style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;">rajat paragraph 1</span>
                            <br><br>
                            <span style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;color:red;">RAJAT INTEREST</span>
                            <br><br>
                            <span style="font-size: 20px;font-family: arial;">rajat Paragraph 2</span>
                          </center>
                        </section>
                        <footer style="height:20px;background: #ecfaff;text-align: center;font-family: arial;">
                            <span>http://biondi.assured.sg</span>
                        </footer>
                      </div>
                    </body>
                    </html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setContent(htmlString)
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png',type: "jpeg", quality: 100})
  await browser.close()
})()
```

I want to create above HTML image. Can anyone please suggest me library for this?

Comment: I am not sure if you are asking for this, but it could work: 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45207479/a-similar-solution-to-html2canvas-with-nodejs

Comment: @NoOne, No i am not using ejs. I just have html saved in variable and i want to create image from that.

Comment: to use dynamic values in string literals you can use  ${} and pass your value inside curly braces as \`static value ${dynamic value}`. 

Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Syntax

Comment: @Ariz, I know this. Just gave the sample above. Please let me know the library for that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can render a HTML string to an image in node.js by using [Puppeter](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

> npm install -S puppeteer

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const htmlString = `<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" style="height:200px;width: 200px;border: 1px solid red">
        <header style="height:50px">
            Header
        </header>
        <footer style="height:100px">
            footer
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>`;

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()
  await page.setContent(htmlString)
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'})
  await browser.close()
})()
```

This will create `example.png` in your folder, it's also possible to clip the image or remove the background by adding properties https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagescreenshotoptions

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me, is this module works at node js side?

Comment: Yes, you just need to do `npm install -S puppeteer` to make it work on node.js

Comment: Can you please tell me one more thing?

Comment: I will get form fields values from android app and have to create image by replacing static values in htmlTemplate with those form fields values and then return image to android app.

So, Won't above code open a browser in android app while running that api?

Comment: For that you would need a fully functional server, e.g. with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), which handles the incoming request with the form values and sends them to Puppeteer.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, I applied background image, but it is not coming.

Comment: @Rajat can you update your code with the background image?

Comment: @DanielDoblado, sure sir. Please give me 1 minute.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, I have updated by question with the latest code, i am using.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, Can you please help me regarding this?

Comment: Like @ThomasBrok said you need an express server or something similar to serve the file, instead I would suggest you to upload the image to some service and call it like this `<header style="height:200px;background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/a1ItuWs.jpg');">` I tested this and works.
`

Comment: @DanielDoblado, I am using express server and my html is saved in my variable as you can see.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, Yes it worked. Thanks a lot. You saved my day.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, My image quality is low. It is showing blurry text. Can you please tell me, how can i fix that?

Comment: @Rajat that happens either because the image itself is of low quality (which I don't suspect, since you mentioned it is now low, and not before), or the way your choice of content delivery network processes the image and sends it upon request.

Comment: No, Module is creating image in low quality from starting.

Comment: try adding "await page.screenshot({path: 'example.jpeg', type: "jpeg", quality: 100})" jpeg and the quality

Comment: @DanielDoblado, Tried, But same result.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, It is creating png images instead of jpeg, as i give options written by you. Please have a look at the updated code.

Comment: To increase the quality you can set size the viewport with this `await page.setViewport({"width": 1920, "height": 1080, "deviceScaleFactor" : 1.5 })` as mentiononed here https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/1329

Comment: @DanielDoblado, It is still blur. Can you please find a better solution for it. I don't want full hd image. But it should not be blurry. Thanks.

Comment: You can increase `deviceScaleFactor` as much as you want here is a comparison between a value of `1.5` on the left and `2`(retina display) on the right as you can see the right one is more smooth. https://imgur.com/fzIFBMa But I don't have more ideas on how to help you on this issue.

Comment: @DanielDoblado, Do you know any other library.

Comment: @Rajat as an alternative you could use something like jsdom to create a dom node with your html and then convert the dom node to canvas that can be output as an image but is overly complex to explain here.