# Generating PDF of a Web Page

Tags: node.js, pdf, phantomjs, html-to-pdf

I'm trying to generate a pdf file of a web page and want to save to local disk to email later.

I had tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124992/) approach but the problem here is, its not working for pages like [this](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html). I'm able to generate the pdf, but its not matching with web page content.

Its very clear that pdf is generated before `document.ready` or might be something else. I'm unable to figure out the exact issue. I'm just looking for an approach where I can save web page output as pdf.

I hope generating pdf of a web page is more suitable in Node then PHP? If any solution in PHP is available then it will be a big help or even node implementation is also fine.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: You may need to put a setTimeout to make sure the whole page, including javascript-generated parts of it is ready before rendering it...

Comment: @xybrek I had tried with setTimeout before posting this question but its also no use

Comment: @Vaviloff I had tried the same code snippet mentioned in 'c' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16124992/1111502), except I had changed [url](http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html)

Comment: You get to choose the point where the screenshot is generated. Just make sure the document is actually ready when you do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Its very clear that pdf is generated before document ready

Very true, so it is necessary to wait until after scripts are loaded and executed.

---

You linked to an answer that uses [phantom](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node) node module.

The module was upgraded since then and now supports async/await functions that make script much much more readable.

If I may suggest a solution that uses the async/await version *(version 4.x, requires node 8+)*.

```
const phantom = require('phantom');

const timeout = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

(async function() {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();

  await page.property('viewportSize', { width: 1920, height: 1024 });

  const status = await page.open('http://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/charts/pie.html');

  // If a page has no set background color, it will have gray bg in PhantomJS
  // so we'll set white background ourselves
  await page.evaluate(function(){
      document.querySelector('body').style.background = '#fff';
  });

  // Let's benchmark
  console.time('wait');

  // Wait until the script creates the canvas with the charts
  while (0 == await page.evaluate(function(){ return document.querySelectorAll("canvas").length }) )  {
      await timeout(250);
  }

  // Make sure animation of the chart has played
  await timeout(500);

  console.timeEnd('wait');

  await page.render('screen.pdf');

  await instance.exit();
})();
```

On my dev machine it takes 600ms to wait for the chart to be ready. Much better than to `await timeout(3000)` or any other arbitrary number of seconds.

Comment: but I think its not ideal solution because we don't know exact time of page load! Is there an event for this?

Comment: Yes there is, [onLoadFinished](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html). For the sake of simplicity of example I didn't use it, but to save time you definitely should move main login into this callback.

Comment: I had tried `onLoadFinished` but page is rendering before its get loaded, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o4cg7vob/) is the sample code

Comment: My bad, `onLoadFinished` is irrelevant here — we must wait for the scripts to finish their work. So I changed the answer to wait for only necessary amount of time, no more.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar using the `html-pdf package`.

The code is simple, you can use it like this:

```
pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./YourPDFName.pdf', function(err, res) {
        if (err) {
          console.log(err);
        }
});
```

See more about it on the package page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried this, it seems its only works for local html file but not for remote urls

Comment: Google charts are not reflecting into the PDF. Any way to convert charts also?

Answer (score 0):

When saving HTML to PDF if the page is scripted over a time period we simply need to add a suitable delay so here the results are at 1/2 second (500 ms) and 1 second (1000 ms), you can simply increase more if page is more complex or your communications / PC is slower.

Using Chrome or Edge call the browser with more time allowance.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --headless --print-to-pdf=C:/data/output2.pdf --no-pdf-header-footer --virtual-time-budget=1000 "https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/other-charts/pie.html" && timeout 3 && C:/data/output2.pdf
```

[image]